# How does the audioParam.exponentialRampToValueAtTime work?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am not able to get a sliding change of volume through exponentialRampToValueAtTime of a GainNode.

Here is an example:

```
var context = new AudioContext(),
    osc = context.createOscillator(),
    gain = context.createGain();

osc.frequency.value = 440; // A note
osc.start( 0 );
osc.connect( gain );

gain.gain.value = 0;
gain.connect( context.destination );

gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues( 0 );
gain.gain.setValueAtTime( 0, context.currentTime );
gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime( 1, context.currentTime + 2 );
```

In my understanding this should gradually increase the volume, until reaching 1 (100%) and this whole process should take 2sec. Is this assumption correct?

If it is, why does stay on 0 for 2 sec, and suddenly switches to full volume?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: Did you try `linearRampToValueAtTime`?

Comment: I have, and it works, but I read that linear doesn't sound as good as exponential ramp, so I wanted to try this out. I am writing an envelope generator and I want to test out some options.

Comment: I guess this is how it is supposed to work. Ramp up fast.

Comment: "Note: Exponential ramps are considered more useful when changing frequencies or playback rates than linear ramps because of the way the human ear works." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/exponentialRampToValueAtTime

Comment: There is no sliding, even if I set 15 sec - just goes to gain.gain.value === 1 after the time has passed. This couldn't be intentional. If it was, what is the difference between exponentialRampToValueAtTime and setValueAtTime?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Works for me on both FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that this function does not like 0 value. FF throws "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified". Below code will ramp correctly. See on [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/kqj6HHBE9DltmPk2u2Jx).

```
var context = new AudioContext(),
    osc = context.createOscillator(),
    gain = context.createGain();

osc.frequency.value = 440.0; // A note
osc.start( 0 );
osc.connect( gain );

gain.connect( context.destination );

gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0.0001, context.currentTime); // <-- line of interest

gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, context.currentTime + 10 );
```

**UPDATE:** "A NotSupportedError exception must be thrown if this value is less than or equal to 0, or if the value at the time of the previous event is less than or equal to 0" according [Web Audio specification](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-exponentialRampToValueAtTime-void-float-value-double-endTime). As figured out by @cwilso (see comments).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks! But isn't this a bug? I imagine, there probably is some multiplication starting with the initial value and that's why it's 0 until the very last step. And since the function slows down exponentially, they probably just set the provided value (towards which the slide is going) when it's marginally closer (imperceptible).

Comment: Sample value < 1/Math.pow(2, bitdepth) is 0.

Comment: I think this is the problem: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/Modules/webaudio/AudioParamTimeline.cpp#L232

and this: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/Modules/webaudio/AudioParamTimeline.cpp#L237

This is in Webkit, but it's the same in Blink.

Comment: You absolutely nailed it.

Comment: This is not a bug; it's explicitly stated in the spec.  " A NotSupportedError exception must be thrown if this value is less than or equal to 0, or if the value at the time of the previous event is less than or equal to 0."  (from http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-exponentialRampToValueAtTime-void-float-value-double-endTime)

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @cwilso Thanks for clarifying. Still, no error is thrown in Chrome and Safari, and Firefox is throwing "illegal string error", which makes it pretty confusing.

Comment: There's now a bug filed: crbug.com/480606.  :)

Answer (score 0):

[The docs at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/exponentialRampToValueAtTime) say the value must be positive.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no point of this being a separate answer. And this is true for FF' implementation, not webkit and Blink. Also "illegal string error"... this looks like a "documented bug" with workaround provided. :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MZaragoza: But they did include the essential part here.